# Blueprint IE hack breaks VS designer

Tags: visual-studio, blueprint-css

My client and I have both just independently experienced this.  Given an HTML page like below, when the IE hack is included, conditionally or not, everything above the "First text" is not visible in the VS designer, in 2008 and 2010, and 2008 crashes very frequently, while 2010 only crashes during certain edit ops on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Smart Computer Solutions</title>
    <link href="Styles/Blueprint/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Blueprint/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="header" class="prepend-1 span-23 last">
            <h1 id="smart-computer-solutions">
                Smart Computer Solutions</h1>
            <div id="subheader">
                <h3 class="alt">Some catchy and informative company slogan.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        First text
        <hr />
        Second text
        <div id="top-nav" class="prepend-1 span-23 last">
            Third text
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm also asking this on the Blueprint forum, but SO is my primary oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys on the Blueprint discussion group have convinced me the problem is with the VS designer, not the IE hack.  I agree here - the design view in VS is still pathetic.